# How can I call a groovy script from a Jenkins file?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am trying to separate out the contents from a Jenkinsfile into a groovy script to make. But it fails to call these scripts:
Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

node('test-node'){

  stage('Checkout') {
    echo "${BRANCH_NAME} ${env.BRANCH_NAME}"
    scm Checkout

  }

  stage('Build-all-targets-in-parallel'){

    def workspace = pwd()
    echo workspace
    parallel(
      'first-parallel-target' :
       {
         // Load the file 'file1.groovy' from the current directory, into a variable called "externalMethod".
         //callScriptOne()
         def externalMethod = load("file1.groovy")
         // Call the method we defined in file1.
          externalMethod.firstTest()
       },
       'second-parallel-target' :
      {
         //callScriptTwo()
         def externalMethod = load("file2.groovy")
         // Call the method we defined in file1.
         externalMethod.testTwo()
        }
    )
  }
  stage('Cleanup workspace'){
    deleteDir()
  }
}
```

file.groovy

```
#!groovy

def firstTest(){

  node('test-node'){
    
    stage('build'){
      echo "Second stage"
    }
    
    stage('Cleanup workspace'){
      deleteDir()
    }
  }
}
```

Looks like the Jenkinsfile is able to call file1.groovy but always gives me an error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method firstTest() on null object
```

Comment: I don't think  `load("file1.groovy")` is finding your groovy file try to debug that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to have methods available in your `Jenkinsfile` from an external file you need to do the following

In your `file1.groovy`, return references to the methods

```
def firstTest() {
    // stuff here
}

def testTwo() {
    //more stuff here
}
...

return [
    firstTest: this.&firstTest,
    testTwo: this.&testTwo
]
```

**EDIT**

`evaluate` does not seem to be required

```
def externalMethod = evaluate readFile("file1.groovy")
```

or

```
def externalMethod = evaluate readTrusted("file1.groovy")
```

And as mentioned by @Olia

```
def externalMethod = load("file1.groovy")
```

should work

Here is a reference on [`readTrusted`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-multibranch/#code-readtrusted-code-read-trusted-file-from-scm). Note that no parameter substitution is allowed (does a lightweight checkout)

From lightweight checkout:

> If selected, try to obtain the Pipeline script contents directly from the SCM without performing a full checkout. The advantage of this mode is its efficiency; however, you will not get any changelogs or polling based on the SCM. (If you use checkout scm during the build, this will populate the changelog and initialize polling.) Also build parameters will not be substituted into SCM configuration in this mode. Only selected SCM plugins support this mode.

At least that works for me

Comment: Can you please help me understand what evaluate can do.

Comment: Your choice of return is very nice and very much tied to the function. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe the evaluation is only required when using `readFile`, so `evaluate readFile(file)` is the same as `load(file)`. You can also use `return this`, but I prefer the scoping. Looking at the link posted by @Olia also suggest that the evaluation is not required.

Comment: Pipelines also support [`readTrusted`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-multibranch/#code-readtrusted-code-read-trusted-file-from-scm), that allows reading files without doing full fletched checkout

Comment: @Rik how can i use readTrusted with full checkout? any idea?

Comment: @ealeon the idea about readTrusted is that you do not need to do a full checkout. If you want to do a full checkout to read the file just use `readFile`, as in the example `node {checkout scm; readFile 'subdir/file'}` from [readTrusted](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-multibranch/#code-readtrusted-code-read-trusted-file-from-scm) docs. If you mean something different, could you provide a bit more context for what you want to achieve?

Comment: @rik yes i went with checkout scm and readFile route

Answer (score 13):

It looks like you missed return within the scripts you are loading:

```
return this
```

Please, check it here:
https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-cps/#load-evaluate-a-groovy-source-file-into-the-pipeline-script

So, your called loaded file will have a structure like:

```
def exampleMethod() {
    //do something
}

def otherExampleMethod() {
    //do something else
}
return this
```

This way you shouldn't get null object