# groovy script loaded from jenkinsfile not found

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

currently I have an "all inclusive" jenkinsfile which contains various functions.
In order to re-use those functions in other jenkinsfiles I want to put them into separate groovy scripts and load them from the jenkinsfile(s).

scmHandler.groovy:

```
 #!groovy
 def handleCheckout() {
    if (env.gitlabMergeRequestId) {
       echo 'Merge request detected. Merging...'
    }
    ...
 }
 return this;
```

in `jenkinsfile` I do:

`...
 def scmHandler = load ("test/scmHandler.groovy")
 scmHandler.handleCheckout()`

I tried to follow the instructions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43324268/how-can-i-call-a-groovy-script-from-a-jenkins-file) but jenkins is constantly complaining that there is no such file `scmHandler.groovy` an I get:

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: d:\jenkins\workspace\myJenkinsJob\test\scmHandler.groovy`

Both jenkinsfile and scmHandler.groovy reside in a `test/` subdir of the workspace in the git repo of the project to boild and are checked out correctly on master:

```
    /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/myJenkinsJob/workspace@script/test/scmHandler.groovy
```

However I cannot find them on the slave node where the jenkinsfile executes the build steps inside a `node {}`. There I only see old versions of the jenkinsfile since the (separated) checkout step is not executed yet.

How do I correctly access the handleCheckout.groovy? What am I miss here?

Actually I find this a neat way to "include" external groovy files without using a separate library.

Answer (score 1):

Use `checkout scm` before loading `scmHandler.groovy`

```
checkout scm
def scmHandler = load ("test/scmHandler.groovy")
scmHandler.handleCheckout()
```